# Creation of Cauchy density from $N(0, \sigma_1^2)$ and $N(0, \sigma_2^2)$ random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I searched for "cauchy density derivation" but I didn't find any relevant results in the first couple pages.

**Problem:**

Given $X \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)$ and $Y \sim N(0, \sigma_2^2)$, $X \perp Y$, I am supposed to derive the density of $U = \frac{X}{Y}$.

My result was $f_U(u) = \frac{\sigma_1 \sigma_2}{\pi(u^2 \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_1^2)}$. I suspect that this is incorrect since according to Wikipedia the density should be something like $\frac{\sigma_1 \sigma_2}{\pi(u^2 + \sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2)}$.

I reproduce my work below.

**Attempt:**

If $U = \frac{X}{Y}$, then let $V = Y$. From the change of variables formula, I have that

\begin{align}
f_U(u) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lvert v \rvert f_{X, Y} (uv, v)dv\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lvert v \rvert \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_1 \sigma_2}e^{- \big(\frac{u^2 v^2}{2\sigma_1^2} + \frac{v^2}{2\sigma_2^2} \big)}dv\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lvert v \rvert \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_1 \sigma_2}e^{- v^2\big(\frac{u^2 \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_1^2}{2\sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2} \big)}dv.
\end{align}

Now I consider

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} v \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_1 \sigma_2}e^{- v^2\big(\frac{u^2 \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_1^2}{2\sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2} \big)}dv\\
\end{align}

and use the substitution

\begin{align}
s &= v^2\Big(\frac{u^2 \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_1^2}{2\sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2} \Big)\\
ds &= v\Big(\frac{u^2 \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2} \Big)\\
\end{align}

which gives me

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_1 \sigma_2} \cdot \frac{\sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2}{u^2 \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_1^2} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s}ds &= \frac{\sigma_1 \sigma_2}{2\pi(u^2 \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_1^2)}.
\end{align}

A little bit of hand-waving allows me to conclude that

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lvert v \rvert \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_1 \sigma_2}e^{- v^2\big(\frac{u^2 \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_1^2}{2\sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2} \big)}dv &= 2 \cdot \frac{\sigma_1 \sigma_2}{2\pi(u^2 \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_1^2)}\\
&= \frac{\sigma_1 \sigma_2}{\pi(u^2 \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_1^2)}\\
&= f_U(u).
\end{align}

I would appreciate if anyone can point out my mistake(s), if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider the standard normal random variables $W = X/\sigma_1$ and $Z = Y/\sigma_2$ obtained from $X$ and $Y$.  Then $X/Y = (\sigma_1/\sigma_2) W/Z$, so you if you find the
density of $W/Z$ you can find that of $X/Y$.

Comment: Professor, thank you for your hint. I considered independent standard normal random variables $W$ and $Z$ and used essentially the same procedure as above to determine that if $A = \frac{W}{Z}$, then $f_A(a) = \frac{1}{\pi(a^2 + 1)}$. I am 99% sure this is correct. I then considered the transformation $C = \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}A$ and after consulting my notes I determined that $f_C(c) = \frac{\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}}{\pi \big( c^2 + \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_2^2} \big)}$. Not what I was expecting, but it does look plausible according to Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do not understand where I erred in my original attempt, but I will look at it again tomorrow.